# Where is the report for finding "votes" for the comments you leave?

Tags: support, data-explorer

What is the location to the (I believe SQL style query) report that allows you to view your comments sorted by upvotes?

I'm not especially familiar with the place where you can write your own SE queries. I remember being linked to this report at some point but can no longer find it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: As a general hint, there are plenty of queries available on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be looking for [this query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158463/my-top-comments).

Just enter in your User ID that's associated with the site you are trying to search, and the minimal score of your comments to display.

Comment: ah thanks, yeah that was the URL i couldn't recall :)